# Why do Bitwise XOR ( ^ ) given example results differ? What is the logic? JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, bitwise-xor

A non-empty array A consisting of N integers is given. The array contains an odd number of elements, and each element of the array can be paired with another element that has the same value, except for one element that is left unpaired.

For example, in array A such that:

```
A[0] = 9  A[1] = 3  A[2] = 9
A[3] = 3  A[4] = 9  A[5] = 7
A[6] = 9
```

the elements at indexes 0 and 2 have value 9,
the elements at indexes 1 and 3 have value 3,
the elements at indexes 4 and 6 have value 9,
the element at index 5 has value 7 and is unpaired.
Write a function:

```
function solution(A);
```

that, given an array A consisting of N integers fulfilling the above conditions, returns the value of the unpaired element.

For example, given array A such that:

```
 A[0] = 9  A[1] = 3  A[2] = 9
 A[3] = 3  A[4] = 9  A[5] = 7
 A[6] = 9
```

the function should return 7, as explained in the example above.

```
function different(a) {
  let result = 0;

    for (let element of a) {
        result ^= element
    }

  return result;
}

const arr = [9, 3, 9, 3, 9, 7, 9];
```

I found this solution which works pretty well with the required condition. I didn't understand use of Bitwise XOR ( ^ )

I also tested with different arrays;

```
 arr = [9, 3, 9, 3, 9, 7, 9];  //returns 7 
 arr = [9];                    //returns 9
 arr = [9, 3];                 //returns 10
 arr = [9, 3, 9, 3];           //returns 0
 arr = [9, 3, 9, 9 ];          //returns 10
 arr = [9, 3, 9, 2 ];          //returns 2
```

Could anyone explain to me how it works? What is the logic behind it? Why does it only work perfectly with the required condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works because when you `XOR` a number with `0`, you get the number, and when you `XOR` a number with itself, you get `0`. For your specific conditions of an array with only one unpaired number (`[9, 3, 9, 3, 9, 7, 9]`), you can unroll your loop to look like

```
result = 0 ^ 9 ^ 3 ^ 9 ^ 3 ^ 9 ^ 7 ^ 9
```

and since

```
a ^ b = b ^ a
```

this can be rewritten as

```
result = 0 ^ 9 ^ 9 ^ 3 ^ 3 ^ 7 ^ 9 ^ 9
       = 0 ^ 0 ^ 0 ^ 7 ^ 0
       = 7
```

The reason this doesn't work when there is more than one unmatched value is that the result you end up with is the `XOR` of all the unmatched values. For example, for `[9, 3, 9, 9]` you get

```
result = 9 ^ 3 ^ 9 ^ 9
       = 9 ^ 3 ^ 0
       = 10
```

Comment: I upvoted this answer because it's correct, but also ...if you're doing bitwise math in Javascript, especially on the front-end, it's *probably* a bad idea.  In some very specific cases there's a good reason to, but if you don't have a specific good reason, you're likely making your code unnecessarily difficult to maintain, with no real benefit.

Comment: @machineghost agreed, it's certainly not how I would write the code, but OP just wanted to know why it worked.

Comment: Yeah, sorry that comment was intended more for OP, not you, but since it was addressing the "answer part" I put it here.  And it must have been two downvotes, or someone changing their upvote to a downvote, because I saw a 2 a second ago (and it wasn't me; you still have my upvote).

Comment: @machineghost yeah, someone either changed their up to a down or someone else downvoted and the other person removed their upvote. Either way I don't understand it and would have appreciated knowing why...

Answer (score -1):

Before answering the main question you should know how XOR works. For even number of same bits, the bit of xor is 0 and for odd number of bits, the xor bit is 1. The truth table of XOR-
A   B   XOR
0   0    0
0   1    1
1   0    1
1   1    0

Now to your reasoning:

lets say you want to XOR, note intermediate sates are binary representation

- 2^2 = 10 ^ 10 = 00 = 0 (in base 10)
- 2^2^3 = 10^10^11 = 11 = 3 (in base 10)
- 1^2^3 = 01^10^11 = 00 = 0 (in base 10)

  Notice the false result? I hope now you know how XOR works. So it will work only if the number is paired in the array and will find out only the one unpaired number correctly.